# Jenkinsfile java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps

Tags: jenkins, marathon, jenkins-pipeline

I get the below strange error when trying to deploy to MESOS.

The snippet of code looks as follow

```
marathon(                          
    url: 'http://marathon-instance', 
    forceUpdate: false,              
    appid: 'someid',                 
    docker: 'mesosphere/jenkins-dev')
```

Unfortunalety it fails with below error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps [acceptGitLabMR, addGitLabMRComment, archive, artifactoryDownload, artifactoryPromoteBuild, artifactoryUpload, bat, build, catchError, checkout, collectEnv, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, echo, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, getArtifactoryServer, git, gitlabBuilds, gitlabCommitStatus, input, isUnix, load, mail, marathon, milestone, newArtifactoryServer, newBuildInfo, node, parallel, properties, publishBuildInfo, pwd, readFile, readTrusted, retry, script, sh, sleep, sshagent, stage, stash, step, svn, timeout, timestamps, tool, unarchive, unstash, updateGitlabCommitStatus, waitUntil, withCredentials, withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, ws] or symbols [all, always, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, batchFile, booleanParam, buildButton, buildDiscarder, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, choice, choiceParam, clock, cloud, command, cron, crumb, defaultView, demand, disableConcurrentBuilds, downloadSettings, downstream, dumb, envVars, file, fileParam, filePath, fingerprint, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, git, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, installSource, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jnlp, jobDsl, jobName, junit, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, myView, nodeProperties, nonStoredPasswordParam, none, paneStatus, parameters, password, pattern, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, run, runParam, schedule, scm, scmRetryCount, search, security, shell, slave, stackTrace, standard, status, string, stringParam, swapSpace, text, textParam, tmpSpace, toolLocation, unsecured, upstream, viewsTabBar, weather, zfs, zip]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:145)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:117)
```

I can see I have the marathon 1.3.2 plugin installed. However, something appears to be wrong.

Antoine

Comment: Are you sure that this is all your code? It seems there is just some misplaced `$` somewhere.

Comment: Yes I check, if I comment the marathon line, everything is working

Comment: @AVoiry Did you ever find the cause of that?